# jQuery: multiple groups, each with global selector

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a page to manage e-mail subscriptions and I'm having trouble figuring out the *Un-subscribe from all* per-group option.

**Problem**

My problem is that I don't know how to make the *Un-subscribe from all* option activate the radio buttons in the Un-subscribe column that correspond to that specific group.

While checking the radio buttons in the Un-subscribe column I also need to add a class `.selected` to their labels in order to style them to visually help communicate that the option has been selected.

Also note that within a specific group, when a *Subscribe* option is checked, the *Un-subscribe from all* checkbox of that specific group becomes unchecked and the class `.selected` is removed.

I know it's a bit confusing (or a lot), so I've created a ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/JpmFc/1/)*** of this.

As you will see in the JS comments, I am able to select the radio buttons, but all radios buttons of all groups get checked instead of the specific group of radio buttons.

I've also tried using the `.parent()`, `.parents()`, `.closest()` methods, but I'm just not able to make it work.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8MHHa/1/

```
$(".unsubs-chkbx-group").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('table').first().find('.opt-out input:radio').attr('checked', true);
    $(this).parents('table').first().find('.opt-out label').addClass('active');
    //$('.opt-out input:radio').attr('checked', true);
    //$('.opt-out label').addClass('active');    
});
```

Comment: Man, I was so close. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks Keith!

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I'm unable to remove the class `.active` from the corresponding Un-subscribe label. What I did removes the class `.active` from all Un-subscribe labels in all groups. Here's what I've tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/JpmFc/6/ Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like the following:

```
$(".unsubs-chkbx-group").change(function() {
    var $table = $(this).closest('tbody');

    // uncheck all
    $('tr:not(.group) input', $table).prop('checked', false);
    $('label', $table).removeClass('selected');

    if(this.checked) {
        var $elements = $('.opt-out', $table);
        $('label', $elements).addClass('selected');
        $('input', $elements).prop('checked', true);
    }
});

$('tbody input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var $row = $element.closest('tr');
    $('label', $row).removeClass('selected');

    $element.parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

​

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpmFc/8/)

Comment: "Tocallo" this is great. However, I'm unable to uncheck the checkbox and remove the class `.active` from the corresponding Un-subscribe label if the *Subscribe* option is selected. Does that make sense? Here's what I've tried so far but it doesn't quite work the way I need it: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/JpmFc/6/ - If you check any *Subscribe* option, all *Un-subscribe* options get the class `.active` (`.selected`) removed. Thanks man.

Comment: This is great! The only thing missing is when selecting all *Un-subscribe* options from a group, then the *Un-subscribe from all* checkbox for that group should get selected as well. Tnx in advance!